# Non-key-preserved table error for update with unique data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am confused about key preserved join view update in Oracle (and in general); when doing an update using a select with a join, whether the key preserved property is expected for the table that is updated or for the embedded select statement.

In the below example:

```
SQL> create table tabX (x1 number, x2 number);

Table created.

SQL>  create table tabY (y1 number, y2 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into tabx values (1,11);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tabx values (2,12);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into taby values(1,21);

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into taby values(2,22);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

the output of select is unique but still the update fails. There is no ambiguity or duplication in both select and update - so why does it fail?

```
SQL> select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1;

        X2         Y2
---------- ----------
        11         21
        12         22

SQL> update (select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1) set x2=y2;
update (select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1) set x2=y2
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know there is no duplication, but when the statement is parsed the optimiser doesn't know there isn't, and more importantly that there *can't be*, any duplication. The parser looks at statistics to decide how to work but in general doesn't look at data. The update statement may be cached and reused, so even if it did look and saw there were no duplicates right now, the data might have changed when the same statement is run again later from the cache.

Imagine you added an extra row:

```
insert into taby values(2,222);
```

then your query gets:

```
select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1;

        X2         Y2
---------- ----------
        11         21
        12         22
        12        222
```

Now the update has two possible values to set both `x2=12` values to; should they both be 22, or both 222, or one of each? Oracle has no way of knowing what is right and can't choose which of the first two options should be used (and certainly can't use the third).

Now, that isn't your actual situation, but you need to tell Oracle that the situation cannot occur. The wording of the error is hint here; for the view to preserve a key, there must be a key. If you define `tabY` with a primary or unique key:

```
create table tabY (y1 number primary key, y2 number);

insert into taby values(1,21);

insert into taby values(2,22);
```

then my made-up third insert isn't allowed, Oracle knows that, and can apply that knowledge to the update:

```
update (select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1) set x2=y2;

2 rows updated.

select x2,y2 from tabx,taby where tabx.x1=taby.y1;

        X2         Y2
---------- ----------
        21         21
        22         22
```

---

It doesn't matter how many rows you have with `x1=2`, you want them all to be updated to `x2=22`. So `x1` doesn't need to be unique, and you don't need a UK/Pk on that. But `y1` does have to be unique so you know which *single* value of `y2` to use for *all* of those `x1=2` rows.

> What i don't understand is whether the view becomes key preserved based if the columns involved join are declared unique or the actual values that is getting updated.

It's the columns, not the values. But the bit I think I didn't explain well is that because you are doing `set x2=y2` it can see that only the `tabx` table is actually being updated; so it needs to be able to identify which rows on the `tabx` table are being affected, and then it needs to work out for each of those rows *which* matching `taby` row to get the `y2` values from - which it gets from the join condition.

For each `x2` being updated it has to identify a single `y2` value to use, which it does by looking for the `taby` row where `taby.y1` is *that row's* `tabx.x1`.  If there was - or just could be - multiple rows in `taby` which match that condition then it wouldn't know which of those options to use - 22 or 222 in my example. There has to be a single match in `taby`, so `y1` has to be unique, and has to be **declared** as unique via a UK or PK.

There could be lots of different `x2` values that get updated to the same `y2` value; you could also have

```
insert into tabx values(2,13);
insert into tabx values(2,14);
etc.
```

and all of those would still be updated to the same value - 22 - because the non-unique `x1` value in all of those rows still maps to a single `ytab` row with that tables UK/PK via the join condition.

Comment: Ok, So clearly we need a PK/UK when we use updateable join view. What i don't understand is whether the view becomes key preserved based if the columns involved join are declared unique or the actual values that is getting updated. I checked both, if i declare the column to be updated as unique, it  errors.unique on join columns succeeds. What am i missing here? thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many rows you have with `x1=2`, you want them all to be updated to `x2=22`. So `x1` doesn't need to be unique, and you don't need a UK/Pk on that. But `y1` does have to be unique so you know which *single* value of `y2` to use for *all* of those `x1=2` rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a key, as AlexPoole suggested, you could easily turn it into a MERGE statement (this is something we try each time we encounter the "non-key-preserved" error when updating a view) :

```
MERGE 
 INTO tabx
USING taby
   ON (x1 = y1)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET x2 = y2
;
```

Comment: The data still has to be unique to avoid an "ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables" error; but if that is true then this works without a key.